# Keyof as generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to force someone that want to update an object to pass a the key to update with a correct value type.
As seen in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbn0OMcqIFdSAjBKwC+rXADNuqAMbA6aKNzAATYsAgAeACpQIADzWoliKAGsIIZGNgIUqAHwAKZPUZU4SNABpT5qpu8AbsQANtxc7rYA2poAugCUbjbyeIRQdFYOZiCYGFgARCTkeXE4bKkE8BDA3PDoKeUNAHTNznSMnmUNhIVcQaEQnalCnUI6wYjQ6VCZ5jn5HBDFpV1QldW1yyuEzY2t7YNdC1R9YQcEw0NjE5sNazXoeyO4w7jBVQqoJqjIAO6oEfIsPUCD0qHkAKqfb5-PIdVJHKAATmRz1Yki+v3+SXQWEUKjUDnR0KxHlQ3jyC1hUAAjAAGOJoqGYgE4hTKVQQQlMv4s8mU8nUgCsxVYQA) typescript seems unable to understand that if the `key` has a certain value the `value` variable has a correct type.
While calling the function the type checking is correct and don't allow to pass inconsistent values with the key.

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
};

function update<T extends keyof Person>(orig: Person, key: T, value: Person[T]): Person {
    if (key === "name") {
        return {
            ...orig,
            name: value  // Error: number not assignable to string
        }
    } else if (key === "age") {
        return {
            ...orig,
            age: value  // Error: string not assignable to number
        }
    } else {
        return orig
    }
}

let unknownPerson = {
    name: "Unknown",
    age: 999
};
unknownPerson = update(unknownPerson, "age", 10);
unknownPerson = update(unknownPerson, "age", "15");  // Ok expected number
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvEyrm) meet your needs?  The compiler is unable to narrow generic type parameters like `T` via control flow analysis; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and linked issuses for what's going on.  My refactoring makes this no longer generic, but instead defines `key` and `value` as elements of a discriminated union tuple; the compiler is much happier about control flow narrowing of discriminated unions.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is technically correct to warn you inside the implementation of `update()`.  The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` can be `"name"` or `"age"`, but it can *also* be the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"name" | "age"`.
It is possible (though not likely) for someone to call `update()` with a `value` that doesn't match with `key`, because of this.  For example:

```
update(unknownPerson, Math.random() < 2 ? "name" : "age", 100); // no error
// function update<"name" | "age">(
//   orig: Person, key: "name" | "age", value: string | number): Person
```

So the compiler does not assume that checking `key` has any implication on the type of `value`. If `key === "name"`, the compiler can narrow the type of `key`, but it does not narrow the type parameter `T`.  And hence the error.

This is a known issue in TypeScript, and there are a few open feature requests intended to deal with it. See [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to read more.  For now though, this is just how it is.

If you need to write generic functions this way, then you might have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error.

---

But in your case, you don't really need generics here. Instead, you can refactor the function signature so that the `key` and `value` function parameters are represented as elements of a [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) whose type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Like this:

```
type KeyValueTuple<T> =
    keyof T extends infer K ? K extends keyof T ? [key: K, value: T[K]] : never : never;

function update(orig: Person, ...[key, value]: KeyValueTuple<Person>): Person {
    if (key === "name") {
        return {
            ...orig,
            name: value
        }
    } else if (key === "age") {
        return {
            ...orig,
            age: value
        }
    } else {
        return orig
    }
}
```

The type function `KeyValueTuple<T>` takes a type `T` and produces a union of tuples whose first element is the key type (generally a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)) and whose second element is the corresponding value type.  You can see how this behaves with `Person`:

```
type PersonKeyValueTuple = KeyValueTuple<Person>;
// type PersonKeyValueTuple = [key: "name", value: string] | [key: "age", value: number]
```

And then after the `orig` argument, we package `key` and `value` into a rest argument of type `...[key, value]: KeyValueTuple<Person>`.  Note that inside the function implementation `key` and `value` are seemingly distinct variables, but the compiler treats them as [destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) so checking `key` does have the required implication for the type of `value`.

And so the above compiles with no error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbn0OMcqIFdSAjBKwC+rXGNwAbCMCjdUAa1TIA7qjhI0mHGwIlyVAEQBVBUtUGANDqgcuATge4RuOYpVqEKdFm5gAJsTAEAAUrmYeGqgWUAa2llAAjAAMAJSsYe7qXlq+AUGhppmeaNGxnPEGCQCsBmniAGZyAMbAdJq5gRAA8shgiAA8ANJQEAAeQah+iFDyECDI9bDFqAB8wcj0jFRZJTNzVIPRAG7EEtxcO6gA2oMAuik4UEIu-p09fQVuqpfRALKBAAsAHTwYiTZCkYIPfpQABMUAA-DE9BADFBDHFoslUswoAB6PFEZAjeDwDa4AlQRqoFptdAdIL9AwotEAHxicTWGzoWyWkWisxAhhZUHZZVRx1O5yoNHoTFFPH4CBSVCOyDofjEoEgUEGcwAalKIAAVXxSfrGlaYayChZQY0jcYQSbTBj1BC6xGesYTKZ7eaLB1Iq6Cg6Ss5cY03W63dFECBHD1UVAJwRa8DQS56kCGiOmsBSLTZ3PnfPmy4rViU7WZ5bFo1l6BYEP7ZFkCVQE4RmW0BiMWPsltCjnlcPSxUCeC3MTU2ntV75bm8n5QIFrodjiC3A4GhtmiD9CsqvnZPCEKB0RbBQWYDBYZnt2rac-n+DSbjwdBnl8-tdApdWD+P4oqqRr4oSyDyMQIDWOezxwSMEiINAl5QNecy3vecQPN+P5vsAH5frBQF-gBxE-rYoERuBUCQdB5FPNYQiIchz5AfhhG0ZsTFOEAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a clone of the original object and then update the specified key with the given value:

```
function update<T extends keyof Person>(orig: Person, key: T, value: Person[T]): Person {
    const result = { ...orig };

    result[key] = value;

    return result;
}
```

This way you also don't have to implement special handling for each possible key.

Comment: The problem is that I have to validate the provided data before update the object.

Comment: You could just perform your validation before the assignment and if it fails return early

Comment: If I do it before the assignation the value type is not correct as posted in my question

Comment: Could you update your question and show how you want to do the validation? You might have to cast the value parameter to the correct type, because I don't think TypeScript can infer the type of a variable from the type of a different variable.

Comment: The point is not how to validate, I know that i can cast `value` to whatever I want, but is that I define `key` to be a key of `Person` and value to have type `Person[T]` but it does not work as expected.